# How to active Hijri calendar in Microsoft Access 2010 for client

Tags: ms-access-2010

How can make my `Mirosoft Access 2010` to show date and date pickers in Hijri calendar?

I have a ms access package that need to be in persian calander how can activate it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Options > Client Settings > Check `Use Hijri Calendar`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using in one of my project both date formats. I switch conditionally (if user has selected Hijri date format for specific form then it switches to Hijri else Gregorian) switch between the formats using `Application.SetOption "Use Hijri Calendar", True`